# split and group in panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have Panda DataFrame which looks following:

### Input

```
Name    Key Val
David   A   1
Roe     B   2
John    A   3
Nat     B   4
```

I want to split by Key and Group by Name.

### Output

```
Name    A   B
David   1   nan
John    3   nan
Nat     nan  4
Roe     nan  2
```

Can you please suggest a way to do it?

Below is code to generate the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
# Initializing the nested list with Data-set
data = [['David','A',1],
        ['Roe','B',2],
        ['John','A',3],
        ['Nat','B',4]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Key','Val'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reshaping like this, `set_index` with Name and Key creating a multiIndex, then `unstack` the inner most index level to create columns:

```
df.set_index(['Name','Key'])['Val'].unstack()
```

Output:

```
Key      A    B
Name           
David  1.0  NaN
John   3.0  NaN
Nat    NaN  4.0
Roe    NaN  2.0
```

Comment: Great answer. Suppose have 4 columns in the initial table. 4th column say 'comment'. But I still want the split table to be df.set_index(['Name','Key'])['Val'].unstack(). I want to discard, 'comment' column. In that case, it will error out.

Comment: hmm..I think one way is cleanup those unnecessary columns and then use method you suggested. But not sure if there is way to apply the above method, without deleting columns which I don't need in split table.

Comment: If you have extra columns you can add them to the index to keep that information just after Name before key.

Comment: Hi Scottt - Thanks for your help. I'm still facing some issue which I have put together below. Can you please put some comments when get sometime. Thanks, Dib

Answer (score 0):

Example input data:

```
data = {"Id": ["DA0445EA", "DA0445EA", "DA0445EA", "DA0445EA", "DA0445EA"],
        "Port" : [1,1,1,1,1],
        "Lane" :[None,None,None,None,None],
        "Key" : ["start_now", "start","case","case_start","end"],
        #"val": [0.000001,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]
        "Val":[0.000001,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5] #need to capitalize this 'val' to match dataframe definition below
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Id', 'Port','Lane','Key','Val'])
df1 = df.set_index(['Id', 'Port','Lane','Key'])['Val'].unstack()
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

Exapected output:

| Id | Port | Lane | start_now | start | case | case_start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DA0445EA | 1 | nan | 0.000001 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 0.5 |

Issue I'm getting:

1. all floating number are shown as NAN
2. individual columns (Id, Port, Lane) aren't shown as columns

Comment: I edited your solution.  You need to capitalize 'val' to match you columns in your dataframe constructor this is why you were getting NaNs.

Comment: so helpful Scott. I'm facing another issue (hopefully last one). Below is the scenario I give.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"Id": ["DA0445EA", "DA0445EA", "DA0445EA", "DA0445EA", "DA0445EA"],
        "Port" : [1,1,1,1,1],
        "Lane" :[None,None,None,None,None],
        "Key" : ["start", "start","case","case_start","end"],
        "Val":[0.1,0.1,0.3,0.4,0.5] 
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Id', 'Port','Lane','Key','Val'])
df1 = df.set_index(['Id', 'Port','Lane','Key'])['Val'].unstack()
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

Below is Error generated. The reason is "*There is two duplicate entry for same id*". Such entry is unavoidable for datatable I'm working on. I was expecting, It will overwrite same line in table and won't throw any error like below.

```
raise ValueError('Index contains duplicate entries, '
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Is there a way to avoid such error during Re-shaping?

Comment: ah.. now this duplicate entrie error leads to a a whole different solution is needed.  You're going to need to groupby or pivot_table with some sort of aggregration.  Take a look at this post(https://stackoverflow.com/a/47152692/6361531).

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Finally I could make it work using pivot.